# Extract string and remove it from extracted column, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['my text your text']})
```

I want to extract part of string in column `A` which is `my text` to column `B` and remove it from `A` after extract.

First thing that I will do in that case is propably create B column and after that subtract B from A, but is there any better solution to do that?

```
df['B']=df['A'].str.extract('(my text)') 
df
                   A        B
0  my text your text  my text
```

Expected output:

```
             A        B
0    your text  my text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `\s*` for remove trailing whitespaces and `n=1` for replace only first match:

```
df['B']=df['A'].str.extract('(my text)') 
df['A']=df['A'].str.replace('\s*(my text)\s*','', n=1)
print (df)
            A        B
0   your text  my text
```

Comment: hello, when I am using extract() with regex, its taking first match and extracting it, when i will use str.replace() with same regex it will always find same match ? or will replace all matches in string ? I am asking, because i want to be sure that i am replacing same part of string

Comment: @sygneto - it repalce all matches

Comment: okay, so to get same replacement as str.extract let's add first match, in `.str.replace('(my text)','', 1)`, and that will be what i need :)